# How do I add the modified date of my folder files to my GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-io

I have made an application that successfully display the files in folder in a `asp:GridView` and allows the user to download.

**Here is my code behind:**

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(strDirectory));
List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
}
GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Here is my GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
EmptyDataText = "No files uploaded" CssClass="mGrid" PageSize="20" 
AllowPaging="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" 
            CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" 
            OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to do now is add the date modified in a gridview column so that my users will have an easier time finding the correct documents customers call about. How do I go about this?

Comment: To get the dateModified, use `File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to have more detail than the file name in the `GridView` as the `Directory.GetFiles()` method only returns paths.  In your code, try using something like this instead of `Directory.GetFiles()`:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(strDirectory));
List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles().ToList();

GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The `DirectoryInfo` class provides much more detailed information about file system objects and gives you much more data (you can also filter based on file extension).  By using this, you won't have to do any extra work to get details about the file and in your `GridView`, you'll have access to many properties of each file (including the modified date, name, and many others) by using the `GetFiles()` method of the `DirectoryInfo` class.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
EmptyDataText = "No files uploaded" CssClass="mGrid" PageSize="20" 
AllowPaging="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Modified" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" 
            CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" 
            OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

- Directory Info Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx
- File Info Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried this solution and cannot figure out what to do with my for each loop. I tried this:

foreach (var di in files)
  {
   files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
  }
however this breaks because filepathis is not defined

Comment: This is the error its giving me DataBinding: 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.

Comment: I had to remove the command argument for the download to get rid of the error.

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams  Assuming you want to pass the file name as the command argument, you can just replace the word value with `Name` as name is the file name property of the `FileInfo` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateTime date = directory.GetLastWriteTime;
```

for the file you can use

```
File.GetLastWriteTime
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
```

Here is complete detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FileInfo Class after getting the FilePaths. And this fileinfo has the properties like LastWriteTime,CreationTime , using these attributes you can sort and show. Like inside loop you need to use like this in code behind

> ```
>     FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(filePath );
> ```

and Use

> fi1.LastWriteTime